# Javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query - Something wrong with JpaTransactionManager bean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-transactions

It seems like Spring is unable to find the `JpaTransactionManager` bean that I have created inside my `DBConfig` class.

DBConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
class DBConfig{
    private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;

    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(String DBType, String DBServerName){ 

        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 5000);
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "");
        properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_nappings", false);
        
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties (properties);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan ("**");
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(DBType.equals("MSSQL") ? getMSSQLDataSource (DBServerName): getDB2DataSource (DBServerName));
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("PERSISTENCE_UNIT");
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    

    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(){
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
    }


    @Bean("myTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager myTransactionManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lc = getLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean( "DB2", "<DB_SERVER_NAME>"); 
        return new JpaTransactionManager(lc.getObject());
    }
}
```

When I am trying to execute a delete query as a transaction in my `Test` class, it is throwing `Javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query`

Test class:

```
@Component
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private DBConfig dbConfig;

    @Transactional("myTransactionManager") 
    public void test() {

        Query query = dbConfig.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager().createNativeQuery("<Some Delete Query>");
        query.executeUpdate(); // Error: Javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query 

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use proper ways to obtain the `EntityManager`. Just do `@PersistenceContext EntityManager` in your class. Don't inject the config and don't get the `EntityManagerFactory` like that. ALso you are using Spring Boot, so why are you even doing all that configuration Spring Boot already provides all of that (and more) for you.

Comment: Hey @M.Deinum I am doing it this way because DB config is not known at the start of the application. Hence I can't expose `EntityManagerFactory` as a spring bean.
So I am trying to use a placeholder `EntityManagerFactory` instance at the start of  the application (which is what I have done above) and then later when the DB configuration will be available, I will use `setEntityManagerFactory` method of `JpaTransactionManager` and replace the placeholder instance with another instance of `EntityManagerFactory` with proper DB config. Not sure if this approach will work but I am trying it.

Comment: It won't as the `@Transactional` requires a thread bound `EntityManager` as you are creating your own, you will also need manual transaction management. Nonetheless you can still expose the `EntityManagerFactory` as a bean make it lazy or scoped to the request/session that way it will create a proxy.